# Convert JSON to ORC [AWS]

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, orc, aws-glue

This is my situation: 
I have an application that rotates json files to an s3 bucket. I would need to convert those files in ORC format to be consulted from Athena or EMR.
My first attempt was a lambda programmed in Node, but I didn't find any module for the conversion. 
I think it can be done more easily with GLUE or EMR, but I can not find a solution.

any help?

Thanks!

Comment: have you seen [orc-tools convert](https://orc.apache.org/docs/tools.html#java-convert)? Should be able to write a lambda in Jave using that.

Comment: @avigil I'm going to investigate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use glue. You will need a glue data catalog table that describes the schema of your data, you can create this automatically with a glue crawler.

Then create a glue job, if you follow the Add Job wizard you can select ORC as a data output format on the data targets section of the wizard.

If you go through the tutorials on AWS glue it will step you through doing something similar but converting into Parquet format, if you go through the same steps with your data but select ORC it should do what you want.

Comment: any platform agnostic tools?